# Azure Data Factory script indexing for pipeline().parameters that are used multiple times in the query

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory script to create parameterized SQL query. I understand that the Index specifies the position in which the parameter's value should go in the SQL command. However, I don't know how to handle the situation where pipeline().parameters are used multiple times in the SQL query. In my example below, the RUN_DATE parameter is used twice. When I simply add the same parameters multiple times, it will show "Parameters with duplicate name will be overwritten." Any idea how to solve this?

Here is the query:

```
@concat('
UPDATE s
SET INSERT_DATE = ''', pipeline().parameters.RUN_DATE,'''',
',UPDATE_DATE = ''', pipeline().parameters.RUN_DATE,'''',
'FROM p 
WHERE p.ID = s.ID
AND s.ID = ''', pipeline().parameters.ID,'''',
';')
```

See the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the ask 100% here . The scripts which you shared does use the parameter ID and Run_date and since the parameters are accessible through out the lifetime of the pipeline , so even if you do not pass as script parameter , you script will still work fine .

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Did you mean that as long as the two parameters are listed, they can simply be listed in any sequential order, regardless of the Index? If that's the case, what's the purpose of the Index? Actually, ADF allows the parameters to be in different sequential orders by using mouse dragging. See the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/XHYoXoK

Answer (score 0):

- As @Himanshu said, the pipeline parameters can be referred to script directly. I repro'd it with few changes in the script. below is the approach.
- Pipeline parameters `RUN_DATE` and `ID` are taken.

[image]

- Script activity is taken, and same script is given in the query text box.

```sql
@concat('
UPDATE s
SET INSERT_DATE = ''', pipeline().parameters.RUN_DATE,'''',
',UPDATE_DATE = ''', pipeline().parameters.RUN_DATE,'''',
'FROM p
WHERE p.ID = s.ID
AND s.ID = ''', pipeline().parameters.ID,'''',
';')
```

- When pipeline is run in this way, error will not be as said in the question post. But error produced for this script is,

[image]

- Concat function in adf gives the output value as wrapped within double quotes.
  [image]
- To overcome this, script is modified and given as

```sql
update s
set INSERT_DATE = @{pipeline().parameters.Run_date},
UPDATE_DATE= @{pipeline().parameters.Run_date}
from p
where p.id=s.id and s.id= @{pipeline().parameters.ID}
```

[image]

- When pipeline is run, it is executed successfully.
  [image]

[image]